# Array getting destroyed when thread exits in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I was trying to use threading for parsing two different types of files. The subroutines share no data at all.

```
# Parse header files
 $hdr_thrd = threads -> create(\&Parser::parse_header_file, $path);

 # Parse input template files
 $tmplt_thrd = threads -> create(\&TemplateParser::parse_template);

 # Join the threads
 $tmplt_thrd -> join();
 $hdr_thrd -> join();

 # This uses the data obtained from the above two threads
 &Parser::parse_xml_template();
```

The problem comes when the `parse_xml_template` function tries to access an array `@TemplateParser::array`. The array has no data at this point but it is getting filled inside the `parse_template` function. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you create two threads (for a total of three) when you only need two?

Comment: no the array is not shared and I am creating only two threads($tmplt_thrd and $hdr_thrd). 
I didn't get 'for a total of three' ?

Comment: The array is already a package wide variable. Should it be shared?
If I try to declare it as `@TemplateParser::array :shared;` I get a compile time error.

Comment: YEs, since you want to share it between the main thread and `$tmplt_thrd`. Well, what's the error? You need to use `use threads::shared;`

Comment: There's also the fact that `@TemplateParser::array` isn't a declaration. `my @array :shared;`. If you're trying to access it across package, `our @array :shared;` might do or `share(@TemplateParser::array);` otherwise. I'm not sure, since I've never tried, since this is a terrible thing to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to share data across threads without sharing it. You need to use `:shared` or `share()` on the variable.

You wouldn't have this problem at all if you were to avoid global vars as you should.

```
sub parse_template {
   my @tmplt_result;
   ...
   return \@tmplt_result;
}

my $hdr_thrd   = threads->create(\&Parser::parse_header_file, $path);
my $tmplt_thrd = threads->create(\&TemplateParser::parse_template);

my $tmplt_result = $tmplt_thrd->join();
my $hdr_result   = $hdr_thrd->join();
```

(Explicit sharing is not necessary to when returning a value via `join`.)

Of course, that needlessly creates two threads (for a total of three) when two would suffice. Instead, you could use:

```
sub parse_template {
   my @tmplt_result;
   ...
   return \@tmplt_result;
}

my $hdr_thrd = threads->create(\&Parser::parse_header_file, $path);
my $tmplt_result = TemplateParser::parse_template();
my $hdr_result = $hdr_thrd->join();
```

Comment: I got it answered from the combo of 2nd comment and the answer. Didn't actually make it a local variable but added share() to it and used only one thread.